# cant move head and horns of a deer together

Tags: animation, rigging, auto-rig-pro

[image]i just riggeed a deer, and trying to animate it. But the problem I am facing is, whenever I try to move the body of the deer the body or the head part moves but not the horn. I came to know that both body and horns are two objects individually, so I tried to join them with ctrl + J and put them in same collecttion by selecting them both and hit the M button. But still they are separated and not moving together like they should.
What's the solution??????

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Hi. This is common problem that happens when you have separate (loose) meshes. The calculation of automatic weights often fails then. You need to fix it manually. Figure out the name of the bone that moves the head, e.g. "head" or "DEF-spine.006". Then check the vertex groups of the model and see if there is a group with exactly the same name, e.g. "head". Switch to *Weight Paint* mode and the head be displayed in red. Now, switch to *Edit* mode, select the horns (key L to select linked). Finally, assign the selected verts to the "head" vertex group. Create one if needed.

Comment: Last but not least, if the horns are a separate object, make sure they have the *Armature* modifier on it. If not, select armature, select horns and *Parent To > With Empty Groups* (key Ctrl+P).